# Can't type in Xcode assistant editor

Tags: xcode

A little ashamed to have to ask this, but I'm new to iOS dev, being mostly an Android guy. I'm trying to edit two files at once, side by side, since I'm refactoring and moving functions around.

I did some looking around and found that I can use the assistant editor in manual mode to open any file I want. However, I'm unable to edit anything in this right hand editor. I've used Xcode a tad before at a past job and don't remember having this problem.

Am I doing something wrong here?

At first I thought I had opened a framework file or something outside my project, but that is definitely not the case. I also restarted Xcode, and that didn't help.

Comment: I forgot about this question, but you were right. I'm not sure how that could be the default, but whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the Assistant Editor, the default thing that appears on the right for most code files is the **interface** of the given file. Interfaces are generated files and they can't be modified directly.

You can verify whether the file on the right is an interface by checking whether its name has an "(Interface)" suffix:

[image: "(Interface)" suffix of a file name]

Comment: Just to clarify on top of this answer, you can change to an editable version by clicking on `Automatic` and choose the according `.swift` file